# How to add second icon in Inno Setup

Tags: icons, inno-setup, ico

I'm trying to add second .ico file to use it as icon for files, associated with my application.
Piece of code:

```
[Registry]
Root: HKCR; Subkey: ".tc65"; ValueType: string; ValueName: ""; ValueData: {#DispatcherName};   Flags: uninsdeletevalue;
Root: HKCR; Subkey: {#DispatcherName}; ValueType: string; ValueName: ""; ValueData: {#MyAppName}; Flags: uninsdeletekey;
Root: HKCR; Subkey: "{#DispatcherName}\DefaultIcon"; ValueType: string; ValueName: ""; ValueData: "{app}\{#MyAppExeName},1" 
Root: HKCR; Subkey: "{#DispatcherName}\shell\open\command"; ValueType: string; ValueName: ""; ValueData: """{app}\{#MyAppExeName}"" ""%1""" 

[Icons]
Name: "{group}\{#MyAppName}"; Filename: "{app}\{#MyAppExeName}"
Name: "{commondesktop}\{#MyAppName}"; Filename: "{app}\{#MyAppExeName}"; Tasks: desktopicon
Name: "{userappdata}\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Quick Launch\{#MyAppName}"; Filename: "{app}\{#MyAppExeName}"; Tasks: quicklaunchicon
```

As I understood, this line

```
Root: HKCR; Subkey: "{#DispatcherName}\DefaultIcon"; ValueType: string; ValueName: ""; ValueData: "{app}\{#MyAppExeName},1"
```

says to use second icon for associated files. How to create this icon with known path? Tried several variants in [Icons] section, but without success.

Maybe I should add an icon to exe before compiling it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `[Icons]` section is for creating shortcuts.  It has no relationship to file associations whatsoever.

In order to set the icon to use for an association, you need to set the `DefaultIcon` key to the path to the icon.  This can either be a loose `.ico` file installed via a `[Files]` entry or (preferred) an icon resource compiled into your executable file.

The value you have in your question will tell Windows to use the second icon resource compiled into your executable.

Don't forget to also enable the `ChangesAssociations` setting.

Comment: perfect, thank you very much! In case someone would face this problem: I've replace 3rd line in [Registry] section for this: Root: HKCR; Subkey: "{#DispatcherName}\DefaultIcon"; ValueType: string; ValueName: ""; ValueData: "{app}\pic\fileIcon.ico".